# Weird dark spot of my model

Tags: modeling, shaders

Around the lips of my model, there's a weird dark spot above and below the lips. It shows up in the viewport and render (if you look closely). I've checked normals and duplicate verts.
[image]

[image]

Here's a view of the geometry:
[image]

Comment: That's duplicate geometry, I guess. Just try to move some of the faces around this spot to check. If this does not help, consider uploading your mesh.

Comment: It's imho bad modeled and has a topology problem. That's where most probably the weird shading comes from. To test it apply a sds modifier. The weird shading will most probably be gone. - First i would get rid of the tri that points down to the lip. Then i would get rid of the ngon right in the face where the tri is pointing at. And the one edgeloop around the mouth that should normally come from the nose is too close to the other edgeloop.